# Does current OpenCL implimentions of Java offer cross-platform support as well as stability to be used in projects?

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, real-time, opencl

**Background:**
Our school entered in a competition where my team (based on 3 people including me) is assigned the task to do navigation and image processing. It's an year long project but I want to get started as soon as possible and see what are the options I have. University and other firms are funding in this research as well. I am no computer science major, we are building an engineering application that highly depends on navigation and image processing for basis of intense calculation purposes on top.

**Question:**
I understand we will be needing algorithms and smart data structure choices to cut down the processes and split the work in threads to harness the power of the device. Anyhow, I have been reading a lot regarding OpenCL implementations for Java that I found namely, LWJGL, JOCL, JavaCL. The problem is, they all do the same thing but some does it better in their own unique ways. I am looking for something simple with fair amount of community and cross-platform support. Because, the microcontrollers we will buy most probably run Linux (I am thinking Arduino and SMARTGPU).

Anyways, this is very early so I need some pointers as to where to go from here. I will probably need to look up some guides, tutorials, and manuals as well to understand more on OpenCL.

Comment: Look at your end goal with OpenCL and see what each version of OpenCL gives you and how this would affect your end goal in terms of performance or requirements. Java may not be the best answer for running on small devices though even if it is cross platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using JavaCL for nearly a year now and have found it to be easy to use and reliable.  The one bug that I did find was fixed within 24 hours (admittedly a very simple bug).  I did try using JOCL but found their API to be a little difficult to use compared to JavaCL.  I have no experience with LWJGL, but would point out that LWJGL is more general as it is intended for games.

If you decide to use Java, then I would suggest starting with JavaCL.

However, I would suggest that you consider OpenCV as it provides a lot of image processing functions that have already been heavily optimised.  It may not be as fast as using OpenCL and a fancy embedded GPU but it could cut your development time.

Comment: Ok so after intensive research I settled with JavaCL. It seems to be the best option out there. I do think AMD's Aparapi framework has potential as well.